# How to get the thrown exception using Assert.That, à la Assert.Throws<T>

Tags: .net, nunit, nunit-2.5.9

I have some code which asserts an exception is thrown when a method is called, and then asserts various properties on the exception:

```
var ex = Assert.Throws<MyCustomException>(() => MyMethod());
Assert.That(ex.Property1, Is.EqualTo("Some thing");
Assert.That(ex.Property2, Is.EqualTo("Some thing else");
```

I'd like to convert the `Assert.Throws<T>` call to use the `Assert.That` syntax, as that is my personal preference:

```
Assert.That(() => MyMethod(), Throw.Exception.TypeOf<MyCustomException>());
```

However, I can't figure out how to return the exception from this, so I can perform the subsequent property assertions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can use `Assert.That` to return the exception like `Assert.Throws`. You could, however, still program in a more fluent style than your first example using either of the following:

**Option 1** (most fluent/readable)

```
Assert.That(() => MyMethod(), Throws.Exception.TypeOf<MyCustomException>()
    .With.Property("Property1").EqualTo("Some thing")
    .With.Property("Property2").EqualTo("Some thing else"));
```

**Option 2**

```
Assert.Throws(Is.Typeof<MyCustomException>()
    .And.Property( "Property1" ).EqualTo( "Some thing")
    .And.Property( "Property2" ).EqualTo( "Some thing else"),
    () => MyMethod());
```

**Pros/Cons:**

- The downside is hard-coding property names .
- The upside is you have a single continuous fluent expression instead of breaking it up into 3 separate expressions. The point of using `Assert.That`-like syntax is for it's fluent readability.

Comment: Cheers. I find that when I chain constraints together, I loose the detail about which constraint cause the assertion to fail. I also find the separate constraints clearer as to what each statement is checking for. Looks like I'm going to stick with my original after all :(

Comment: @MPritch, those are very valid points and I didn't realize you lost detail about which constraint would cause the fail. Thanks for pointing that out.